# Array and file creation basic Java Array Problem

Tags: java, arrays

I happen to be having a hard time with a problem. A test will be coming up soon for me and I'm just not so sure as to how to get this problem done. (Nothing too advanced) My main issue is that the reading of and creating the final file. the problem is right below. Any help is appreciated, thanks!
**I've been told to add a summary due to the difficulty to understand what im asking. So essentially you have a file, text.txt and the program takes said file and adds all the numbers in it, spaces make the numbers distinguished and if a zero is at the front it needs to get taken away. All numbers are separated (whatever number of spaces are between them) is all separated with a space + space and a space = at the end followed by space the result of the addition.** I'm looking for help as how to:

**a) Make the new file**

**b) Make the +s and =s**

**c) Transferring from the original file**

**d) How to do the addition (dealing with large space gaps and doing the summing)**

**IM STILL VERY NEW TO JAVA SO ANY LONGER EXPLANATIONS WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED**

---

The approach you are to implement is to store each integer in an array of digits, with one digit per array element.  We will be using arrays of length 25, so we will be able to store integers up to 25 digits long.  We have to be careful in how we store these digits.  Consider, for example, storing the numbers 38423 and 27.  If we store these at the “front” of the array with the leading digit of each number in index 0 of the array, then when we go to add these numbers together, we’re likely to add them like this:

```
38423
27
```

Thus, we would be adding 3 and 2 in the first column and 8 and 7 in the second column.  Obviously this won’t give the right answer.  We know from elementary school arithmetic that we have to shift the second number to the right to make sure that we have the appropriate columns lined up:

```
38423
   27
```

To simulate this right-shifting of values, we will store each value as a sequence of exactly 25 digits, but we’ll allow the number to have leading 0’s.  For example, the problem above is converted into:

```
0000000000000000000038423
0000000000000000000000027
```

Now the columns line up properly and we have plenty of space at the front in case we have even longer numbers to add to these.

The data for your program will be stored in a file called sum.txt.  Each line of the input file will have a different addition problem for you to solve.  Each line will have one or more integers to be added together.  Take a look at the input file at the end of this write-up and the output you are supposed to produce.  Notice that you produce a line of output for each input line showing the addition problem you are solving and its answer.  Your output should also indicate at the end how many lines of input were processed.  You must exactly reproduce this output.

You should use the techniques described in chapter 6 to open a file, to read it line by line, and to process the contents of each line.  In reading these numbers, you won’t be able to read them as ints or longs because many of them are too large to be stored in an int or long.  So you’ll have to read them as String values using calls on the method next().  Your first task, then, will be to convert a String of digits into an array of 25 digits.  As described above, you’ll want to shift the number to the right and include leading 0’s in front.  Handout #15 provides an example of how to process an array of digits.  Notice in particular the use of the String method charAt and the method Character.getNumericValue.  These will be helpful for solving this part of the problem.

You are to add up each line of numbers, which means that you’ll have to write some code that allows you to add together two of these numbers or to add one of them to another.  This is something you learned in Elementary School to add starting from the right, keeping track of whether there is a digit to carry from one column to the next.  Your challenge here is to take a process that you are familiar with and to write code that performs the corresponding task.

Your program also must write out these numbers.  In doing so, it should not print any leading 0’s.  Even though it is convenient to store the number internally with leading 0’s, a person reading your output would rather see these numbers without any leading 0’s.

You can assume that the input file has numbers that have 25 or fewer digits and that the answer is always 25 digits or fewer.  Notice, however, that you have to deal with the possibility that an individual number might be 0 or the answer might be 0.  There will be no negative integers in the input file.

You should solve this problem using arrays that are exactly 25 digits long.  Certain bugs can be solved by stretching the array to something like 26 digits, but it shouldn’t be necessary to do that and you would lose style points if your arrays require more than 25 digits.

The choice of 25 for the number of digits is arbitrary (a magic number), so you should introduce a class constant that you use throughout that would make it easy to modify your code to operate with a different number of digits.

Consider the input file as an example of the kind of problems your program must solve.  We might use a more complex input file for actual grading.

The Java class libraries include classes called BigInteger and BigDecimal that use a strategy similar to what we are asking you to implement in this program.  You are not allowed to solve this problem using BigInteger or BigDecimal.  You must solve it using arrays of digits.

The sample program of handout #18 should be particularly helpful to study to prepare you for this programming problem.  It has some significant differences from the task you are asked to solve, but it also has some similarities that you will find helpful to study.  The textbook has a discussion of the program starting in section 7.6.

You may assume that the input file has no errors.  In particular, you may assume that each line of input begins with at least one number and that each number and each answer will be 25 digits or fewer.  There will be whitespace separating the various numbers, although there is no guarantee about how much whitespace there will be between numbers.

You will again be expected to use good style throughout your program and to comment each method and the class itself.  A major portion of the style points will be awarded based on how you break this program down into static methods.  As with the sample program in handout #18, try to think in terms of logical subtasks of the overall task and create different methods for different subtasks.  You should have at least four static methods other than main and you are welcome to introduce more than four if you find it helpful.

Your program should be stored in a file called Sum.java.  You will need to include the files Scanner.java and sum.txt from the class web page (under the “assignments” link) in the same folder as your program.  For those using DrJava, you will either have to use a full path name for the file sum.txt (see section 6.2.2 of the book) or you will have to put the file in the same directory as the DrJava program.

Input file sum.txt

```
82384
204 435
22 31 12
999 483
28350 28345 39823 95689 234856 3482 55328 934803
7849323789 22398496 8940    32489 859320
729348690234239     542890432323 534322343298
3948692348692348693486235  5834938349234856234863423
999999999999999999999999    432432 58903 34
82934 49802390432  8554389   4789432789   0 48372934287
0
0 0 0
7482343 0   4879023     0 8943242
3333333333   4723  3333333333 6642 3333333333
```

Output that should be produced

```
82384 = 82384
204 + 435 = 639
22 + 31 + 12 = 65
999 + 483 = 1482
28350 + 28345 + 39823 + 95689 + 234856 + 3482 + 55328 + 934803 = 1420676
7849323789 + 22398496 + 8940 + 32489 + 859320 = 7872623034
729348690234239 + 542890432323 + 534322343298 = 730425903009860
3948692348692348693486235 + 5834938349234856234863423 = 9783630697927204928349658
999999999999999999999999 + 432432 + 58903 + 34 = 1000000000000000000491368
82934 + 49802390432 + 8554389 + 4789432789 + 0 + 48372934287 = 102973394831
0 = 0
0 + 0 + 0 = 0
7482343 + 0 + 4879023 + 0 + 8943242 = 21304608
3333333333 + 4723 + 3333333333 + 6642 + 3333333333 = 10000011364
Total lines = 14
```

Comment: Hello, Cynosuric123, try to format your question and explain it. It is a pain to read it. Also, try to separate the problem on smaller questions (create different questions), it seems it is a long problem and it will be easier for others to help you on smaller problems. Also, try to show what's the code that you have already tried until now.

Comment: tl;dr: Are you asking how to format `38423 ` as `0000000000000000000038423`?

Comment: Not quite, as there is no zero adding into the front of the numbers.

Comment: Asking for the complete solution of a homework assignment / test is not in the scope of this site. You should provide the code that you have written so far, and the problem in your code for which you are blocked. Consider https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166